# What is the explanation for the use of 'transporter sites' in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-transporter

In various episodes (such as [Voy: State of Flux](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/110.htm)) '***transporter sites***' appear to be used for transporting people to and from planets.

Is there any particular explanation for this? From other series, and other episodes of the same series, it appears as if site-to-site transport had been perfected by that point and was no longer a formal requirement.

---

Based on the linked question/answers, seems that the most likely relevant explanation is one of time efficiency?

Within the context of the specific episode, the (large) away team was not in immediate danger. Emergency transporting each individual would have led to a slower total transport time (since locking on each signal and performing the transport would be slower), probably be more energy-expensive, and also riskier (since all calculations for the designated transport site would have had time to be optimized in advance).

[Still seems rather a convenient plot device for the episode, but maybe not as terrible as it seemed on first pass]

Comment: [State of Flux](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/State_of_Flux_(episode)) is a Voyager episode.

Comment: “From other series, and other episodes of this series, it appears as if site to site transport had been perfected by that point” — which episodes in particular indicate this?

Comment: Also, huh? What does site-to-site transport have to do with why they have to go to a designated planet to transport up to the ship?

Comment: Maybe you mean "Why they keep using transporter platforms/ dedicated room, when they could go from/to anywhere ?". At least that's how I understood the question. (A quick answer could be "Poor O'Brien has got to do something"

Comment: It's not the room that I'm wondering about - it's the designated site on the planet surface. Everyone from the away mission is expected to return to a designated site, even though there's no interference or other technical difficulty expected with the transports

Comment: @PaulD.Waite literally nearly every other episode of the same season - site to site transports are performed without fanfare on the ship, as well as on planetary surfaces, regularly

Comment: @blueberryfields: they’re performed, sure, but they don’t appear to be routine or standard procedure; rather something performed when necessary. When an away team is going to a planet, or visitors are being beamed aboard, I believe it’s transporter rooms all the way. We see a lot of site-to-site beamings, but we see the Voyager crew in a lot of difficult circumstances.

Comment: I don't think this is a Duplicate, this question (if I've read it correctly), is why do they go to a specific site 'on the planet' to be beamed back to the ships 'transporter room'. This has nothing to do with site-site: its about why the routine order to 'return to the transport site' on the planet part is needed, when they could be beamed from anywhere on the planet back to the transporter room